# How do I create a subnet using the Google Compute Engine cloud console?

Tags: networking, subnet, google-compute-engine

I am wanting to create a subnetwork as described here:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/beta/subnetworks

How can I do this using the cloud console?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the steps below to create subnetworks from Developer console:

1. From Developer console click Networking.
2. Select Networks from left side.
3. Click on Create a network.
4. On this page you can choose between Custom or Automatic subnetworks and the region for these subnetworks.

For more information you can refer to [this link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/subnetworks#before-you-begin).